# Custom taxonomy and custom post type with custom pagination 404 not found

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

My pagination is throwing a 404 error when the posts from General -> Reading are smaller than my custom number of posts on my custom taxonomy `cities` (custom post type `city`). From what I saw on SO this issue can be fixed usually by using a filter of pre_get_posts, but don't know how to apply it on my case.
I want to mention that in the `taxonomy-cities.php` I am getting posts of a category of a custom taxonomy of a custom post type.

taxonomy-cities.php

```
$cat_ID = get_query_var('cities');
$custom_id = get_term_by('slug', $cat_ID, 'cities');
add_filter('posts_orderby', 'edit_posts_orderby');
function edit_posts_orderby($orderby_statement) {
    global $aPostsIDs;
    $orderby_statement = 'FIELD(ID, '.implode(',',$_SESSION['saved_city_ids']).')';
    return $orderby_statement;
}
$offset     = ($paged - 1) * $num_city_guides_post; 
$args['post_type'] = 'city'; 
$args['posts_per_page'] = $num_city_guides_post; // 5
$args['orderby'] = $orderby; // rand
$args['order'] = $order; // DESC
$args['paged'] = $paged; // 1
$args['tax_query'] = array(
                        array(
                               'taxonomy' => 'cities',
                               'field' => 'id',
                               'terms' =>  array($custom_id->term_id) // 3742
                             )
                    );
}
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : 
  while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
  // some code here
  endwhile; 
else: echo 'No Posts';
endif; 
wp_reset_postdata();
```

For `archive-city.php` I am using this filter in the functions.php and it works fine, but it doesn't get applied to the `taxonomy-cities.php` so I get 404:

```
function portfolio_posts_per_page_city( $query ) {
        if (array_key_exists('post_type', $query->query_vars)) {
        if ( $query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'city' ) 
        $num_city_guides_post = get_option('num_city_post');
        if( empty( $num_city_guides_post ) )
        $num_city_guides_post = 9;

        $query->query_vars['posts_per_page'] = $num_city_guides_post;
        return $query;
    }
}
if ( !is_admin() ) add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'portfolio_posts_per_page_city' );
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question however i recently had the same issue. The following Snippet is in fact the contents of my `taxonomy-template.php` using the standard [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), example [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link#Usage_when_querying_the_loop_with_WP_Query).

> How to properly **paginate custom post type taxonomy**

## The Query

- **Firstly** because it's a taxonomy template, the first line declares `$term` allowing me to access the term array and therefore the taxonomy id, name url etc.
- **Secondly** i'm setting the term id as a variable to be used in the [tax_query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) parameter. This is used to query my custom post type `videos` and then get the taxonomy (category) for the loop, stored in `$term_id`.

## The Fix

- Because i'm looping through the posts and limiting the results, we effectively need to *search* for our remaining posts while excluding the previous results and results thereafter. What this means is quite simple:

> You **must** make your custom post types *searchable* in order for pagination to work:

**Important**:

`'exclude_from_search'   => false,`

---

### Example `taxonomy-template.php`

```
<?php $term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) ); ?>

<?php
$term_id = $term->term_id;
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
  'post_type'       => 'videos',
  'posts_per_page'  => 4,
  'paged'           => $paged,
  'tax_query'       => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => $term->taxonomy,
      'field' => 'term_id',
      'terms' => $term_id
    )
  )
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
  <!-- Loop -->
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php if ($the_query->max_num_pages > 1) :  ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php else: ?>
  <!-- Nothing Found -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe u can solve this without filters.
It`s work for pagination my custom posts types

```
$paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array( 'post_type' =>'cities', 'posts_per_page' => 0, 'paged' => $paged );
$query = query_posts( $args );
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
//Do wordpress Loop
<?php endwhile; else:  include( get_404_template() ); ?>
<?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: posts_per_page I need to set it in the backend, it's dinamic

Comment: if u set posts_per_page = 0 (or -1 i dont remember, sry), wordpress look to your setting in bakend.

Comment: Tried it, not working. And I think know what you mean. I have a Custom setting, in the theme options. In this case it should have taken the number of posts from the General -> Reading.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my custom post taxonomies pagination. Older posts page was coming with a 404 page not found. This issue is related to WP taxonomy slug so you have to rewrite rules for your custom post type taxonomies like this below:

```
function generate_taxonomy_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite ) {

    $rules = array();

    $post_types = get_post_types( array( 'public' => true, '_builtin' => false ), 'objects' );
    $taxonomies = get_taxonomies( array( 'public' => true, '_builtin' => false ), 'objects' );

    foreach ( $post_types as $post_type ) {
        $post_type_name = $post_type->name;
        $post_type_slug = $post_type->rewrite['slug'];

        foreach ( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {
            if ( $taxonomy->object_type[0] == $post_type_name ) {
                $terms = get_categories( array( 'type' => $post_type_name, 'taxonomy' => $taxonomy->name, 'hide_empty' => 0 ) );
                foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                    $rules[$post_type_slug . '/' . $term->slug . '/?$'] = 'index.php?' . $term->taxonomy . '=' . $term->slug;
                    $rules[$post_type_slug . '/' . $term->slug . '/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$'] = 'index.php?' . $term->taxonomy . '=' . $term->slug . '&paged=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index( 1 );
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $wp_rewrite->rules = $rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;

}

add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'generate_taxonomy_rewrite_rules');
```

This should work for all custom post type taxonomies and if you want to be more specific then you can try updating these two variables like this:

> $post_types = get_post_types( array( 'name' => 'city', 'public' => true, '_builtin' => false ), 'objects' );
>
> $taxonomies = get_taxonomies( array( 'name' => 'cities', 'public' => true, '_builtin' => false ), 'objects' );

Finally, just use your default query loop without passing any arguments. Pages will be generated based on General -> Reading.